Why can't I kill this process on Windows
I tried to delete a file and got a popup that said I couldn't because it was in use by "devenv.exe". My Visual Studio is shut down, so I'm not sure what "devenv" is or why it's hanging around. I tried this in powershell:
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-process devenv

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
      0       0      104         56       0.00  50748   1 devenv

PS C:\Windows\system32> taskkill /pid 50748
ERROR: The process with PID 50748 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).

PS C:\Windows\system32> taskkill /pid 50748 /f
ERROR: The process with PID 50748 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.

I'm running Powershell as admin. I'm not very familiar with Windows. Does this mean my OS has become unstable and should be shutdown, or is there another way to kill this devenv thing?

“ Does this mean my OS has become unstable and should be shutdown, or is there another way to kill this devenv thing?” - Your system is stable. Restarting will kill the process or service responsible for you being unable to delete the unknown file.

Use Process Explorer to learn what devenv.exe belongs to and to potentially kill it.

@Destroy666 Is Process Explorer something included in Windows or do I need to download it?
